# Calculating percentages/conditionally summing with stat_summary_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a set of lat/long values with a third variable that can be either -1 or 1. (Sample data: https://pastebin.com/WPq90ka1)

I am mapping this data into hex bins using stat_summary_hex:

```
single <- read.csv(file="mysamplefile.csv",head=TRUE)

pdxMap <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left = -122.844435, bottom = 45.42, right = 
-122.43, top = 45.665316), zoom = 11, maptype = "toner")

ggmap(pdxMap) + 
  coord_equal() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)  +
  stat_summary_hex(data=single, aes(x=LONGITUDE,y=LATITUDE,z = Value),
                   fun = function(z) mean(z),
                   alpha = .9, bins=50) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c('#4393c3', '#ffffff', '#d6604d'))
```

However, instead of doing mean(z), I'd prefer to calculate the percentage of values that are 1, ie: (sum of values that=1)/(sum of all abs(values))

The denominator isn't an issue, but I can't figure out how to manage the numerator. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Found a solution using ifelse: fun = function(z) sum(ifelse(z>0,z,0))/sum(abs(z)))

Comment: Nothing wrong with your solution, but a more readable solution takes advantage of the fact that `as.numeric(T) == 1` and `as.numeric(F) == 0`.  Given this, you could use `sum(z==1) / length(z)`